# PHP Generate unique teams using number combination

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a way to generate teams for a tournament game.
For example there are 12 candidates, and each team has 3 members.
But the part that I cannot figure out is how to do it so that one candidate never is in the team with another  candidate twice.
Because this can be unfair when some candidates are better or worse that the others.
I found many scripts like the one below, but those create all unique combinations, like this;
1,2,3
1,2,4

But this is incorrect because now candidate 1 and 2 are together in a team twice.
Also all candidates have to be in a team with all other candidates once.
Someone has a solution?

Script I found that may helps ;

```
function array_combination($le, $set){
            $lk = combination_number($le, count($set));
            $ret = array_fill(0, $lk, array_fill(0, $le, '') );

            $temp = array();
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $le ; $i++)
                $temp[$i] = $i;

            $ret[0] = $temp;

            for ($i = 1 ; $i < $lk ; $i++){
                if ($temp[$le-1] != count($set)-1){
                    $temp[$le-1]++;
                } else {
                    $od = -1;
                    for ($j = $le-2 ; $j >= 0 ; $j--)
                        if ($temp[$j]+1 != $temp[$j+1]){
                            $od = $j;
                            break;
                        }
                    if ($od == -1)
                        break;
                    $temp[$od]++;
                    for ($j = $od+1 ; $j < $le ; $j++)    
                        $temp[$j] = $temp[$od]+$j-$od;
                }
                $ret[$i] = $temp;
            }
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $lk ; $i++)
                for ($j = 0 ; $j < $le ; $j++)
                    $ret[$i][$j] = $set[$ret[$i][$j]];   

            return $ret;
        }
```

Comment: `$candidates = range(1,12); shuffle($candidates); $teams=array_chunk($candidates,3);`

Comment: Well this is a start, and yes it works, but I forgot to tell that, if it is possible, all candidates have to play with each other once, but also not twice, not sure if that is possible?

Comment: @RoelSQL So at each round do you create a new set of 4 teams from the 12, and want the constraint for each pair of players A, B, A and B play on the same team exactly once?  If so (maybe I'm wrong, just asking), it seems impossible: for any given player A, there are 11 other players team up with, and each game you pair up with 2 new players - so it seems like there's an odd player out?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with minimal amount of code.

check this out:

```
$candidates = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

var_dump(getTeam($candidates));

function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    return array_chunk($candidates, $team_size);
}
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 9
      2 => int 10
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 11
      2 => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 8
      2 => int 7
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 6
      1 => int 12
      2 => int 1
```

this changes every time you refresh.

Comment: After 5 years of experience, I stilllearn new php functions. (array_chunk)

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what im looking for, I may explained not good enough, but is there a way so all candidates are teammates with each other candidates once, without being in a team with another candidate twice?

Comment: You can't do this with just PHP. you'll need database store to keep track of who played who etc... your question is more complex than it is made out to be... my code will get you only so far I guess :(

Comment: I released that yes, but I guess I can also store it into variables right? because only the end results matters, but im wondering if it is even possible to let all players play with all other players without have duplicates in a team?

Comment: Wanted to show an example but stackoverflow wont let me for format it in a comment..